# Pandas Dataframe indexing and grouping

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I'm using a simple dataset of State, County and county population which I'm reading into a df in which I need to get the 3 most populous counties in each state. I'm using this code to do this...

`dfTemp = dfTemp.groupby(['STNAME'])['CTYNAME','CENSUS2010POP'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3, columns=['CENSUS2010POP']))`

The output is correct however I am seeing a column of integers next to STNAME which I can't comprehend...
[output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2SIz.png)
Can someone help explain this please?

thanks

Comment: Do you see those integers in dfTemp before performing the grouping ?

Comment: No dfTemp doesn't have these. I was told separately that these are indices that groupby creates on the fly. I was able to ignore them and derive the desired result but I'm still intrigued by why they have to be shown.